# How can I stop same alert dialog showing every time from handler?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` on a method and the method is used inside a `Handler`. When the `Handler` running every time the `AlertDialog` also loading again and again, I want to show the dialog one time if the dialog is still showing I don't want to load it again. For this I have the below code but not working.

```
     Handler handler = new Handler();
      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
          public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            checkCountry();
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);




public void checkCountry() {

            alertDialogueBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogueBuilder.setTitle("VPN Detected!");
                      alertDialogueBuilder.setMessage("Please Turn Of VPN To Continue!");
   alertDialogueBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.errorstop);
      alertDialogueBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogueBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog =     alertDialogueBuilder.create();

            if(alertDialog.isShowing()){
             //Do Something
            }else{
             alertDialog.show();
            }
   }
```

Comment: Please paste the full code.

Comment: Your code is creating a new alert dialog that has no relation to any alert dialog that might already be showing

Comment: this code will not compile as it has typing error.. Please provide the correct and full code..

Comment: Code updated. please check

Answer (score 0):

Create your `Dialog` only once and not every time:

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
// ...
initDialog();
Handler handler = new Handler();
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        checkCountry();
    }

};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

//...

public void initDialog() {
     alertDialogueBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
     alertDialogueBuilder.setTitle("VPN Detected!");
     alertDialogueBuilder.setMessage("Please Turn Of VPN To Continue!");
     alertDialogueBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.errorstop);
     alertDialogueBuilder.setCancelable(false);
     alertDialogueBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog =     alertDialogueBuilder.create();
}

public void checkCountry() {
     if(alertDialog.isShowing()){
     //Do Something
     }else{
         alertDialog.show();
     }
}
```

Comment: but my country is updating after every 10 second. so I want to use handler.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. I didn't remove your handler-code, I just moved the `Dialog`-building stuff to a separate init method.

Answer (score 0):

To show only 1-time dialog call only this checkCountry() method from which you want to show this dialog. And, please remove the Handler code. No need to use Handler here. Use only checkCountry() method to show the dialog.

Comment: but my country is updating after every 10 second. so I want to use handler.

Answer (score 0):

The oldest trick in the book is to just make a boolean field "isAlertDialogShown" with false initialization, upon creation to true and in the onClick set it to false again (if you want it to be shown again when the handler fires).

```
private boolean isShown = false;    
public void checkCountry() { 
            if (isShown){
             //do something
             return;
             }
            isShown = true;
            alertDialogueBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogueBuilder.setTitle("VPN Detected!"); 
                      alertDialogueBuilder.setMessage("Please Turn Of VPN To Continue!"); 
   alertDialogueBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.errorstop);
      alertDialogueBuilder.setCancelable(false); 
            alertDialogueBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    isShown = false;
                    finish();
                } 
            }); 
            AlertDialog alertDialog =     alertDialogueBuilder.create();

             alertDialog.show();
   }
```

if you want to try and use the alertDialog isShowing you need to use the one you created and not the new one, so again save it as a field, 
but you will still might have an edge case if the handler timer is running too fast, and that is alertDialog.show() is not an immediate operation:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;
public void checkCountry() { 
            if ( alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing){
                //do something
                return;                     
            }
            alertDialogueBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogueBuilder.setTitle("VPN Detected!"); 
                      alertDialogueBuilder.setMessage("Please Turn Of VPN To Continue!"); 
   alertDialogueBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.errorstop);
      alertDialogueBuilder.setCancelable(false); 
            alertDialogueBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                } 
            }); 
            alertDialog =     alertDialogueBuilder.create();

            alertDialog.show();
   }
```